# How to set my for loop count start in 1 instead of 0?

Tags: java, arraylist, console, bufferedreader, filewriter

Can anyone tell me how do i stop my system count start with 0 so if my system(PC) count will give a proper counting for my IDE. sorry for my english i can't explain it clearly but i will show you my problem.

So here's my code.

```
case '2':
                System.out.print("Enter Subject: ");
                SB = buff.readLine();

                File readSUB = new File("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\subject.txt");
                File readN = new File("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\name.txt");
                File readSN = new File ("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\studNo.txt");
                File readSEC = new File("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\section.txt");
                File readTD = new File ("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\TimeDate.txt");

                Scanner scaSUB = new Scanner(readSUB);
                Scanner scaN = new Scanner(readN);
                Scanner scaSN = new Scanner(readSN);
                Scanner scaSEC = new Scanner(readSEC);
                Scanner scaT = new Scanner(readTD);

                while (scaSUB.hasNextLine()) {
                    String a = scaSUB.nextLine();
                    SUBJECT.add(a);
                    break;
                }

                while (scaN.hasNextLine()) {
                    String b = scaN.nextLine();
                    NAME.add(b);
                    break;
                }

                while (scaSN.hasNextLine()) {
                    String c = scaSN.nextLine();
                    STUDNO.add(c);
                    break;
                }

                while (scaSEC.hasNextLine()) {
                    String d = scaSEC.nextLine();
                    SECTION.add(d);
                    break;
                }

                while (scaT.hasNextLine()) {
                    String e = scaT.nextLine();
                    TIME.add(e);
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("\nAttendance List by SUBJECT: "+SB);
                System.out.println("SUBJECT\t\tNAME\t\t\tSTUDENT NO.\t\tSECTION\t\tTIME & DATE\n");

                boolean SUBFound = false;
                for(int x = 0; x < SUBJECT.size(); x++) {
                    if(SB.equals(SUBJECT.get(x))) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(x+SUBJECT.get(x)+"\t\t"+NAME.get(x)+"\t\t"+STUDNO.get(x)+"\t\t"+SECTION.get(x)+"\t\t"+TIME.get(x));
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                    SUBFound = true;
                }

                if(!SUBFound) {
                    System.out.println("No "+SB+" Subject Record Found.");
                }
                break;
```

and Here's the OUTPUT that i want to fix.

```
=======================================================================================
@#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@

[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD

=======================================================================================
Input Number: 3
Enter Section: B1-1AM
Attendance List by SUBJECT: B1-1AM
  SECTION       STUDENT NO.     NAME            TIME & DATE

0 B1-1AM        19-01297        Saludaga Joshua     Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
1 B1-1AM        19-00751        Tatoy Cherrylyn     Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
2 B1-1AM        19-00900        Pulano Hardhie      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
3 B1-1AM        19-01297        Saludaga Joshua     Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18   <= Repeated Output

=======================================================================================
```

as you can see the output still leak some double i dont know how to stop the repeating output i think the counting is the cause of that or my logical i try many way i know to break the loop.
sorry for my english it's not my usual use language.

> JUST ANOTHER UPDATE LOOP STILL GOING EVEN THE LOOP HAVE A BREAK; IF YOU REPEAT REQUEST OUTPUT THE DATA IN FOR LOOP STILL REMAIN HOW DO I FIX THIS?

```
    =======================================================================================
@#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@

[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD

=======================================================================================
Input Number: 2
Enter Subject:PE

Attendance List by SUBJECT: PE
SUBJECT     NAME            STUDENT NO.     SECTION     TIME & DATE

PE      Test Sub 1      19-00001        A1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 20:03
PE      Test Sub 2      19-00002        A1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 20:05

=======================================================================================
@#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@

[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD

=======================================================================================
Input Number: 2
Enter Subject:MATH

Attendance List by SUBJECT: MATH
SUBJECT     NAME            STUDENT NO.     SECTION     TIME & DATE

MATH        Test Sub 3      19-00003        A1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 20:16

=======================================================================================
@#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@

[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD

=======================================================================================
Input Number: 2
Enter Subject:JAVA

Attendance List by SUBJECT: JAVA
SUBJECT     NAME            STUDENT NO.     SECTION     TIME & DATE

JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Tatoy Cherrylyn     19-00751        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Pulano Hardhie      19-00900        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18

=======================================================================================
@#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@

[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD

=======================================================================================
Input Number: 2
Enter Subject:JAVA

Attendance List by SUBJECT: JAVA
SUBJECT     NAME            STUDENT NO.     SECTION     TIME & DATE

JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Tatoy Cherrylyn     19-00751        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Pulano Hardhie      19-00900        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18

=======================================================================================
@#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@

[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD

=======================================================================================
Input Number: 2
Enter Subject:JAVA

Attendance List by SUBJECT: JAVA
SUBJECT     NAME            STUDENT NO.     SECTION     TIME & DATE

JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Tatoy Cherrylyn     19-00751        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Pulano Hardhie      19-00900        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18

=======================================================================================
@#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@

[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD

=======================================================================================
Input Number: 2
Enter Subject:JAVA

Attendance List by SUBJECT: JAVA
SUBJECT     NAME            STUDENT NO.     SECTION     TIME & DATE

JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Tatoy Cherrylyn     19-00751        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Pulano Hardhie      19-00900        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:26
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        B1-1AM      Tue, 12/10/2019 19:18

=======================================================================================
```

Comment: for(int x = 0; x < SUBJECT.size(); x++) { --> x = 0 sets the first value to 0. Just set it to 1

Comment: i already try that sir but the output who ever the first in the list will be move at the last

Comment: the first name in list [0] will be moved at last :(

Comment: Are you sure, that there are no duplicates in your data files?

Comment: Yes Absolutely 100%

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are printing the loop index, just increase `x` by 1 in the print

```
System.out.println((x + 1)+SUBJECT.get(x)+"\t\t"+NAME.get(x)+"\t\t"+STUDNO.get(x)+"\t\t"+SECTION.get(x)+"\t\t"+TIME.get(x));
```